# WPF: ScrollViewer & Grid - Disable TexBox resizing

Tags: wpf, xaml

Consider the following XAML sample.

1. I have a ScrollViewer. In case the windows is too small for the Grid, Srollbars will be visible.
2. In the ScrollViewer is the Grid. All Items within the Grid should stretch to the column width of the grid.
3. Now there are textboxes (with very long text).

My problem is, that the textboxes will be getting bigger and bigger in case the text is getting bigger. But i just want, that the Textboxes fit to the grid space.

**How can i disable the textbox resizing with large Text inside?**

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="26" />
            <RowDefinition Height="26" />
            <RowDefinition Height="26" />
            <RowDefinition Height="26" />
            <RowDefinition Height="26" />
            <RowDefinition Height="26" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="130" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="130" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Label 1"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Tbox1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="asfas fasd fasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asf  safasdf asdf asdf fasasd fas f" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="22" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />

        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Label 2"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Tbox2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="asfas fasd fasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asf  safasdf asdf asdf fasasd fas f" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="22" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />

    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Not sure to understand your issue but if your textbox should always be to a fix width, why don't you set his width to the wanted value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to ensure, that the TextBox won't resize the Grid.

Easiest way is to place the textbox in such **container, that ignores its children's size**, e.g. `Canvas`. You also need to set textbox size by binding it to the column width.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="MiddleColumn" Width="*" MinWidth="130" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="130" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Canvas Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBox Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MiddleColumn}"/>
        </Canvas>

    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

however, notice, that canvas also ingores height of the TextBox and if text is wrapped, the row is not resized. You can workaround it by DataBinding Canvas height to TextBox.ActualHeight. You can encapsulate this layout binding into reusable style:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource IgnoreContentWidthStyle}">
    <TextBox Text="asfasdf asdfad sfa sdf" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</ContentControl>

<Style x:Key="IgnoreContentWidthStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Canvas Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=PART_Content}">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Content"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                      Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"/>
                </Canvas>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Alternativelly, you can create custom element derived from Panel, or Decorator, that will override MeasureOverride and ArrangeChildren and place the textbox inside. This approach gives you better performance, since you avoid the layout bindings.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you have 2 options to stop textboxes getting bigger:

1. Disable horizontal scrollbar
2. Bind textbox max width to another element, like this:

   ```
       <Grid Grid.Column="1" Name="grdWidth"/>

       <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Label 1"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
       <TextBox x:Name="Tbox1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="asfas fasd fasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asf  safasdf asdf asdf fasasd fas f" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
       MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=grdWidth}" Height="22" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />

       <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Label 2"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
       <TextBox x:Name="Tbox2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="asfas fasd fasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asf  safasdf asdf asdf fasasd fas f" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="22" Grid.Column="1" 
       MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=grdWidth}" 
       Grid.Row="1" />

   </Grid>
   ```

I would personally go with the first option

Comment: if you databind maxwidth and you resize window to smaller size, thet the scrollbar will appear

Comment: I agree. OP said: "My problem is, that the textboxes will be getting bigger and bigger in case the text is getting bigger. But i just want, that the Textboxes fit to the grid space." I, personally, don't think that having grid that doesn't fit horizontally is a good think, but that's what OP wants, I believe